# Duplicated request when SocketTimeoutException happens in Android

Tags: java, android, android-networking

Code below sets up connection to server and when readTimeout value(val) expired SocketTimeoutException(just log error in catch section) is thrown but for some reason duplicated request is sent and two tranasction executed on server that obvoiusy is very bad

```
System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) endPoint.openConnection();
final String data = prepareRequestData();
final OutputStream os;

((HttpsURLConnection) connection).setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
        return true;
    }
});
connection.setReadTimeout(val);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Host", endPoint.getHost());
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

Tried to call connection.disconnet() in catch section but it doesn't help. Can anyone explain reason of "magic" duplicated request and how to solve this.

Comment: The question is meaningless unless you show the try/catch structure, and any loops that this is embedded in.